# How to get the value of a model form and assign it to its key in another model form

Tags: django, django-views

Suppose I have three models A, B, and C. I also created two model forms from these models. I want to know that is there a way to get the value of the B model form and assign it to its key in the c model form in views?

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class C(models.Model):  
    a= models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b= models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)


class BForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        CHOICES = B.objects.all()
        model = B
        fields = ('name',)
        widgets = {'name': Select(choices=( (x.id, x.name) for x in CHOICES ))}


class CForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = ('answer',)
        widgets = { 'answer': RadioSelect(choices=RATING_CHOICES),}



def index(request):
    a1 = A.objects.get(id=1)
    a2 = A.objects.get(id=2)
    if request.method == "POST":
        b_form = BForm(request.POST)
        form = CForm(request.POST, prefix='a1')
        form1 = CForm(request.POST, prefix='a2')

        if (form.is_valid and form1.is_valid()):
            b_form.save()
            z = form.save(commit=False)
            z.a= a1
            z.b = # I could not figure out this 
            z.save()

            z = form1.save(commit=False)
            z.a = a2
            z.b = # I could not figure out this
            z.save()
```

Comment: use `related_name` on your model .

Answer (score 0):

Use the `related_name` attribute like this:

**models.py**

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, related_name="as")

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, related_name="bs")

class C(models.Model):  
    a= models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b= models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

**views.py**

```
def your_view(request, pk):
    c = C.objects.get(pk=pk)
    bs_of_c = c.bs.all()
    as_of_c = c.as.all()
    return ...
```

Comment: there is no use of pk in my view as (request, pk), all work is done in one view.

Comment: the point here is to use the `related_name` attribute to get the relations